# How to make two loop print, print on 2 differents lines, without erasing what the other wrote

Tags: python, cmd, printing

I have two functions using two differents processes, and each have a while loop with a print(data + "\r", end="")?

EDIT:
Here is an example of what I'd want:

```
$> First line
$>
$>
$> 5/10 (0%)  < This is what function 1 print
$> 111/400 (0%) < This is what function 2 print
```

And what they do right now is they overwrite what the other write. I'd like them to overwrite their own line and not what the other wrote.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
def print_i():
    i = 0
    while (i < 50000):
        print(i, + "\r", end='')
        i += 1
def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    p.apply_async(print_i, args=(0,))
    p.apply_async(print_i, args=(1,))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: From your comment on `alexDuty`'s answer, you want contradictory functionality.  You want the processes to use a shared resource without damaging each other.  This *requires* that you have some sort of critical region, in which only one process at a time can operate, making all other wait.  Choose what you need and write the coordinating code to match.  This is a common problem in operating systems, and has many posted solutions on line.

Answer (score -1):

try to make a common print handler who get the data from the two function and let it scheduling

Comment: The functions are ran in two differents process so I don't think they could easily communicate I think with Multiprocessing.Queue they may be tho... But I don't want them to wait for the other to write a line